# What is the probability of no white balls

Tags: probability

There are $n$ balls in a box. We add to the box a white ball. After that the ball drawn from the box turns out to be white. What is the probability that initially there was no white balls in the box?
I try to apply the Bayes formula:
$$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B|A) \mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$$
$A = \text{initially there was no white balls}$

$B = \text{the drawn ball after adding 1 white ball to the box is white}$
$\mathbb{P}(B|A) = \text{the probability that the drawn ball is white if initially there was no white balls} = \frac{1}{n+1}$
Am I right that $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{k+1}{n+1}$, where $k$ denotes the initial numer of white balls?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do we know anything about the $n$ balls in the box?

Comment: @AFalseName Nothing more...

Comment: Look up conditional probability if you never heard of it and the Bayes' formula.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I know a little bit of it, but how do you want to apply it here?

Comment: I remember this question being asked with n=3 in my finals. Baffled even a lot of teachers.

Comment: Ehh we didn't really study probablity in depth. It was just a glance at it. And why do you hate geography teacher. Yeah it didnt baffle math teachers ofc.

Comment: Anyway, look up Bayes' formula and then if you still don't manage to do it, edit your question to show that at least you made an effort. Then you will most likely get an answer.

Comment: Its probably worth a mention that the hypergeometric distribution gives the probability for sampling without replacement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question cannot be answered without an assumption about your prior knowledge of the balls in the box. I'll work it out for two relatively plausible assumptions to show what a difference the assumption can make.

If your prior beliefs were indifferent with respect to the number of white balls in the box, you'd assign a prior probability of $\frac1{N+1}$ to each of the $N+1$ possible numbers of white balls. Then the posterior probability for there to have been no white balls before you added one is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P(N=0\mid\text{white ball drawn})
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(N=0\land\text{white ball drawn})}{\mathsf P(\text{white ball drawn})}
\\
&=&
\frac{\frac1{N+1}\cdot\frac1{N+1}}{\sum_{n=0}^N\frac1{N+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{N+1}}
\\
&=&
\frac2{(N+1)(N+2)}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

so it decays quadratically with $N$.

On the other hand, if you drew the balls that were already in the box from a huge box filled equally with white and non-white balls, so for each ball independently you're indifferent whether it's white or not, we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P(N=0\mid\text{white ball drawn})
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(N=0\land\text{white ball drawn})}{\mathsf P(\text{white ball drawn})}
\\
&=&
\frac{2^{-N}\cdot\frac1{N+1}}{\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-N}\binom Nn\cdot\frac{n+1}{N+1}}
\\
&=&
\frac{2^{-(N-1)}}{N+2}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

so the posterior probability decays exponentially with $N$.